# Submitting a Form using Javascript not working properly

Tags: php, javascript, onclick

The problem I am having is when I click the link that submits the form to the next page, it is not sending the info.

The javascript should send the info using the onclick code and the php GET code should pick it up.

What am I doing wrong???

AirportPage.php

```
<form name="searchform2" action="updategeneralinfo.php" method="post" id="searchform2">
 <input type="hidden" id="airport_id2" name="airport_id2" value="search"/>
 </form>



  <a href="../updategeneralinfo.php" onclick="document['searchform2'].submit(); return false;">Update Info</a>
```

---

updategeneralinfo.php

```
$airport_id = $_GET['airport_id2'];



   Airport: <?php echo $airport_id; ?>
```

Comment: is the form tag closed properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Post method
//Airport page

```
<form name="searchform2" action="updategeneralinfo.php" 
method="**post**" id="searchform2">

 <input type="hidden" id="airport_id2" name="airport_id2" value="search"/>
 </form>

  <a href="http://../updategeneralinfo.php"
onclick="document['searchform2'].submit(); return false;">Update Info</a>
```

//Update info page updategeneralinfo.php

```
if(isset($_POST['airport_id2']))
{
  $airport_id=$_POST['airport_id2'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are posting the form but looking at the GET result

Change method to GET or change

`$airport_id = $_GET['airport_id2'];`

to

`$airport_id = $_POST['airport_id2'];`

or use

`$airport_id = $_REQUEST['airport_id2'];`

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php

Answer (score 1):

You are using the method POST , so in your php code , you should be using

```
  $_POST['airport_id2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Either change your **form method="post" to form method="get", OR access $_POST in your php page**.

Answer (score 1):

Forget scripting altogether and use a submit button:

```
<form name="searchform2" action="updategeneralinfo.php" method="post" id="searchform2">
  <input type="hidden" id="airport_id2" name="airport_id2" value="search">
  <button>Update Info</button>
</form>
```

No javascript required.

Comment: Indeed, I was just pointing out that it's a bit silly using script to submit a form when a button can do the job and obviate the scripting.